# Read timeout error in jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, sonarqube-5.0

I get this read time out error in Jenkins, Sometimes it is successful and sometimes there is this error.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) @ bcd ---
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is      platform dependent)
INFO: Work directory:     /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Nightly_build_Project_1.3/workspace/target/sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.0
[INFO] [02:36:52.624] Load global referentials...
[INFO] [02:37:12.706] Load global referentials done: 20084 ms
[ERROR] Unable to request: /batch/global
```

The build gets failed frequently due to this error.

```
[INFO] Pd client project .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO]  ab project ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] bcd ...................................... FAILURE     [01:27 min]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:32 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-09T02:37:12+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/89M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------    ------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project bcd: Unable to request: /batch/global: Read timed out -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.4:sonar (default-cli) on project     bcd: Unable to request: /batch/global
at         org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at     org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Shd i use sonar-maven plugin 2.5+  ??
As in successful builds there is a warning
    Computation of Maven dependencies by SonarQube is deprecated. Please update the version of SonarQube Maven plugin to 2.5+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade the sonarqube to 5.1 . It will work.
There is a issue in 5.0 for multi-modules project while reading a query, which was overcome in 5.1